# Re-ordering an ordered list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list E.G

```
<ol>
  <li NumVotes="3">[Alot of HTML]</li>
  <li NumVotes="2">[Alot of HTML]</li>
  <li NumVotes="1">[Alot of HTML]</li>
</ol>
```

Ordering it initially is fine (C# LINQ), I have a JS filter system whereby you can change the type of items displayed, so I need to re-order the list after the filters change. I need it to be quick, so simply copying the html() around is not really an option.

How can I achieve this?

I looked at the sortable plugin but seems that's just for letting users drag LIs around.

Comment: what's wrong with "copying the html around?" also, `NumVotes` is not valid HTML... you should try `data-numvotes` instead.

Comment: its valid HTML5 isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple sort algorithm will do the trick:

```
var myArray = $("ol li");

myArray.sort(function (a, b) {

    a = parseInt($(a).attr("NumVotes"), 10);
    b = parseInt($(b).attr("NumVotes"), 10);

    if(a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

$("#results").append(myArray);
```

And a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HU5ve/

If performance is really an issue here use a.getAttribute() instead of jqueryish way. I doubt it gets much much better then this.

Comment: It actually _is_ copying some html around, but I think it should be acceptable unless you have a list of thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

Found a tutorial on how to reverse the Ordered List using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    var countli = $('ol > li').size();
    $("ol > li").each(function(i) {
        var attrvalue = countli - i;
        $(this).attr("value",attrvalue);
    });
});
```

Taken from here:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/website-coding/create-a-reverse-order-ordered-list-using-jquery/

Demo:
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_reverse_unordered_list.htm